# Enter key validates the contenteditable

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a title that the user can modify thanks to contenteditable.
I want that when the user presses enter this validates the title instead of passing a line.

```
<div class="panel-participants-title"
     *ngIf="thread.title !== '' ">
    <div class="panel-title"
         contenteditable="true">
           {{thread.title.substring(1)}}
    </div>
</div>


.panel-participants-title:hover > *[contenteditable="true"] {
  background: #989898;
}
.panel-participants-title > *[contenteditable="true"] {
  outline: 0;
}
```

/////UPDATE

```
<div class="panel-participants-title">
     <div class="panel-title"
          contenteditable="true"
          (keypress)= "validateTitle($event)">
              {{thread.title.substring(1)}}
     </div>
</div>

validateTitle(event: any): void {
  if(event.keyCode===13) {
    document.getElementById("panel-title").submit();
  }
}
```

////////UPDATE2

```
validateTitle(event: any): void {
  if(event.keyCode===13) {
    event.preventDefault();
    event.stopPropagation();
    event.submit();
  }
}
```

Comment: Do you have any code to show what you have tried? Pressing Enter on what or when? A bit more information would be nice.

Comment: add an event listener, keydown, check if its enter, then prevent default, and call you function to validate

Comment: @newbie I updated my post

Comment: try event.preventDefault() and event.stopPropagation(); and then the submit.

Comment: @newbie I updated my post with your solution, but it does not work

Comment: do you want to validate a string or do u want to submit a div? I am kinda confused, a snipped could help  :)

Comment: and before you do, check this out: [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/5f9kLupm/13/)

Comment: @newbie I want that when it taps on entry, it validates the selection so that the cursor is no longer in the div

Comment: so u want the div to loose focus?

Comment: @newbie That's it.

Comment: Done: [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/5f9kLupm/16/), I posted it as an answer as well, in case the fiddle gets shut down

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a working example of the fiddle, in case it shuts down :)

```js
document.querySelector('#id1').addEventListener('keypress', function (e) {
    var key = e.which || e.keyCode;
    if (key === 13) { // 13 is enter
       var text = document.getElementById("id1").value;
        if (text.includes("w")) {
         alert("Omg, the string contains a W, try again");
        } else {
       document.getElementById("id1").blur();
        }
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
Input Field <input id="id1" type="text" name="fname">
```

Answer (score 1):

`onKeyPress="if(event.keyCode == 13) validerForm();"`

and

`function validerForm(){
    document.getElementById("formulaire").submit();
}`

Normally that's what you're trying to do. Basically when key number 13 (the Enter key) and presses it launches a function that will validate the form.

Comment: I have this error : `Property 'submit' does not exist on type 'HTMLElement'.`

Comment: try without the submit

Comment: your button and type submit?

Comment: When I try the UPDATE2, I have this error : `event.submit is not a function`